# Is there any library for use Arduino Uno with esp8266-01 module?

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I have a Arduino Uno and the esp8266 module,(NOT THE SHIELD).

I was looking for some library that I could use to connect to Wifi and set a webserver, but I can't find anything. I just found for Arduino Wifi Shield which uses SPI.

It is possible to use arduino lets say to read a LM35 and then send that data to the ESP8266 module and serve it in a page as webserver?

I know that I can use AT commands with ESP8266 to connect to wifi and to create a server, but I cannot find any function to set the data to be served.

https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/4a-esp8266_at_instruction_set_en.pdf

Answer (score 1):

For a webserver, program the ESP8266 directly. This allows you to make use of the internal SPI flash memory to store your webpages. You can't do this with AT commands.

The Arduino UNO does not have enough processing power and/or memory for advanced internet stuff. If you want a webserver over AT commands, the Arduino has to do all the hard work, the ESP8266 is just a dumb slave that establishes a TCP connection.
The ESP8266 is much faster, and has many times more memory, so it makes sense to let it do all the heavy lifting.

Take a look at this guide:
[ESP8266 temperature logger](https://tttapa.github.io/ESP8266/Chap16%20-%20Data%20Logging.html)

You can copy pretty much all code, but instead of measuring the temperature from an actual sensor, read it from the `Serial` input.

Then just connect the Arduino to the ESP8266 over Serial (or SPI or I²C or SoftwareSerial, whatever you prefer), and have it send the temperature to the ESP8266, for example every second.

To program the ESP8266, you can use the USB-to-Serial adapter of one of your Arduinos.

---

In this case, where you just want to read a single LM35, you could even use only the ESP8266. It is true that the LM35 requires at least 4V, but this is not a problem, since most ESP8266 dev boards also provide a 5V supply. The analog input range of 0-1.0V would allow for a temperature up to 100°C.

Comment: No thanks! I was just looking for a tutorial for AT and arduino, I already have something from Expresif but programming the ESP8266 is not what I want to do right now and I don't have the tools required for the job.

Comment: You don't need one. You have an Arduino and a NodeMCU, both of them can be used as a USB programmer for the ESP-01. But you're free to do it the hard way, of course.

Comment: 4 AT commands are harder than wiring and programming esp8266 with arduino? I'm just returning json

Comment: If it were easy, would you come to this site to ask for help? All I'm saying is that it is much easier to use the mature and well-written Arduino ESP8266 Core libraries for network communication, and that it's pretty wastful to use both an Arduino and an ESP8266 if you just want to read a temperature sensor. The most basic temperature logger could be written in ~20 lines, it would work great and have good error handling. From my own experience, I know that it is much more cumbersome to do the same thing using AT commands.

Answer (score 0):

Why involve the UNO at all.  The ESP88266 could be programmed with the Arduino IDE to read the sensor and deal with the internet all by itself.  It doesn't need the UNO to do what you want.

Comment: The sensor that I'm using LM35 needs at least 4V, besides I will need to program the esp8266 and I don't have tools for that, and I bought for provide wifi to arduino. I have a nodemcu too btw

Comment: If you have the tools to program the Arduino UNO then you also have the tools to program the ESP8266.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't google hard enaugh.

There are plenty of examples serving your environment.

This [instructables](http://www.instructables.com/id/Simple-Webserver-Using-Arduino-UNOMega-and-ESP8266/) is just one of it.

> The main aim of this instructable is to show how you can create a simple web server using Arduino and Wi-Fi module which displays the sensor data in the webpage.

Comment: That is not what I need check my description again.